Gortz, Wedhorn, Algebraic Geometry, Proof of Proposition 3.52 - why is there at most one reduced subscheme structure?
Proposition 3.52 in Görtz and Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry reads as follows:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $Z \subseteq X$ a locally closed subset. Then there exists a unique reduced subscheme $Z_{\operatorname{red}}$ of $X$ with underlying topological space $Z$.

I could prove it by taking affine open cover and use the correspondence between closed subschemes and ideals to uniquely find a local closed subschemes and glue them together.
But the first step of the proof on the book goes like:
The previous proposition implies that there exists at most one reduced subscheme with underlying topological space $Z$.
Where proposition 3.51 shows that $f_{\operatorname{red}}$ exists and is uniquely determined for every $f \colon X \to Y$ if we ask $\iota_{X} \colon X_{\operatorname{red}} \to X$ to be a natural transformation at $f$.
How can I see the uniqueness from proposition 3.51?

I think Proposition 3.50 is more useful in this case. Maybe it was a typo?

Suppose $Z_1,Z_2$ are two subscheme structures on $Z\subset X$. Let $Z_0=Z_1\times_X Z_2$, which is a common closed subscheme of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ with the same underlying topological space (proof: since immersions are stable under base change, $Z_0\to Z_i$ is an immersion; for any $z\in Z$, consider the canonical morphisms $\operatorname{Spec} k(z) \to Z_i$ - they are equal after the immersions $Z_1,Z_2\to X$, so they define a morphism to $Z_0$, therefore every point of $Z$ is in $Z_0$; since $Z_0\to Z_i$ is an immersion with closed image, it is a closed immersion). So it suffices to treat the case where $Z_1$ is a closed subscheme of $Z_2$.
Now we can exploit the following remark from proposition 3.50:

If $X'\subset X$ is a closed subscheme of $X$ with the same underlying topological space, then the inclusion morphism $X_{red}\to X$ factors through a closed immersion $X_{red}\to X'$.

So the closed immersion $(Z_2)_{red} \to Z_2$ factors as the closed immersions $(Z_2)_{red} \to Z_1 \to Z_2$, and another application of this shows that $(Z_1)_{red} \to Z_1$ factors as $(Z_1)_{red} \to (Z_2)_{red} \to Z_1$. Consider the following diagram, where we've used that $((Z_i)_{red})_{red}=(Z_i)_{red}$ from proposition 3.50:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(Z_1)_{red} @>>> (Z_1)_{red}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
(Z_2)_{red} @>>> (Z_2)_{red}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
(Z_1)_{red} @>>> Z_1\\
@VVV @VVV \\
(Z_2)_{red} @>>> Z_2\\
\end{CD}$$
The composite morphisms $(Z_i)_{red}\to (Z_i)_{red}$ in the left column must be the identity by the uniqueness condition in proposition 3.51, and each of the morphisms $(Z_1)_{red}\to (Z_2)_{red}$ in the left hand column are the same by construction. Therefore $(Z_1)_{red}\cong (Z_2)_{red}$.

Dear KReiser, thank you very much for this answer. I would have liked to give the bounty to you, unfortunately I was at a wedding this weekend and I could not connect in between. Your answer is clear, thank you again.
